# Variables Not Being Passed To Detail View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an iPad app with UISplitViewController.  I'm trying to update detail view with 3 string properties.

I have the delegate setup but see other examples using `id detailItem`.

DetailView.m

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem {
    if (detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        [detailItem release];
        detailItem = [newDetailItem retain];
        NSLog(@"Text Should be here: %@", self.detailItem);
    }

    if (popoverController != nil) {
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }        
}
```

LeftView.m didSelectRowAtIndex

```
NSString *mystring = @"Test";
detailViewControlleriPad.detailItem = mystring;
```

I want to just pass those 3 strings from left to detail view or even the NSManagedObject which will in turn update a tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/ipad-development/splitview-application-in-ipad/) is a great tutorial I found on how to use a SplitViewController, and pass data from on the detail view to the root view. Hope this helps!